# Haskell Correctly use Multiple Parameters

Tags: haskell

I am trying to make my own "Set" datatype and when I try to declare an insert function the compiler complains about too few arguments:

```
quantities.hs:12:27:
Expecting one more argument to `Set'
In the type signature for `insert': insert :: Set e -> Int -> Set
```

How can I correctly define the insert function to add a new element to my set?

Here is what I have so far:

```
data Set e = Set [e]

mySet :: Set Int
mySet = Set [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

setLength :: Set e -> Int
setLength (Set s) = length s

empty :: Set e -> Bool
empty (Set s) = if null s then True else False

insert :: Set e -> Int -> Set
insert set value = set : value

main = do print(insert mySet 1)
```

Comment: About the error itself: `Set` is not a type, `Set e` is a type. You forgot the `e` in the signature of `insert`.

Comment: `empty` should be written `empty (Set s) = null s`. `if boolean then True else False` is exactly the same as just `boolean`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to implement `insert` like as follows. Note that your type signature isn't correct. You cannot insert `Int` to a set of type `Set e` (you can only insert `Int` to a set of type `Set Int`).

```
insert :: Set e -> e -> Set e
insert (Set s) value = Set $ value : s
```

Note that the above `insert` doesn't take into account of duplicate elements(Hint: use `nub` for eliminating that).

Comment: I get this: Couldn't match type `[e0]' with `Set e0'
    Expected type: [Set e0]
      Actual type: [e]
    In the second argument of `(:)', namely `s'
    In the expression: Set value : s
    In an equation for `insert': insert (Set s) value = Set value : s

Comment: @gravysam I think you are missing `$`according to the error report ? Also see this: http://ideone.com/3LpTPq